Futuristic movie with VR recorded from brainwaves
I'm looking for a movie that has VR recording directly from a person as they experience something.
I want to say this was an illegal, highly restrictive, or grey legal area, as the experiences are so real, since they are transmitted directly to the brain.  I want to say they aren't really interactive, as they are just a recording.
The method of recording is a thin, flexible circuit that apparently works through hair.
The only scene I can remember is one where a "dealer" walks up to a guy in a party/bar and offers him money to have sex with a woman at the party/bar while wearing the recording device.  I remember the recorder basically getting slapped over the guys hair, with a really bad wig being draped over it.
I'm thinking I saw only part of the movie, and it was around 20 years ago that I saw it on TV.  It was color and in English.  I want to say it was an 80's or 90's American movie.
I want to say the "dealer" was Joe Pantoliano, but none of his work around that area seems to match up, just from looking at titles (and their descriptions) of his work at IMDB .

There's a couple of sequences in Strange Days (1995) with Ralph Fiennes that might fit.

Set in the last two days of 1999, the film follows the story of a black marketeer of SQUID discs, recordings that allow a user to experience the recorder's memories and physical sensations, as he attempts to uncover the truth behind the murder of a prostitute.
Wikipedia

One where he sells the idea/technology/experience to a potential buyer.



...and another where he attempts to get someone to create the recroding.

A GAME ARCADE.  Light and noise as the customers drop
quarters for synthetic thrills.  Lenny is talking to a
nice-looking street kid in his early 20's named EDUARDO.

                        EDUARDO
          Let me get this straight... you
          gonna pay me 200 bucks to put on a
          hair net and bang some beautiful
          babe.  I don't know, I gotta think
          about this.

  Lenny smiles and pulls out a SQUID-net.  He motions
Eduardo into the shadows.

                          LENNY
          Okay, let's get you wired up.  I
          hope this axle grease you got in
          your hair doesn't screw up the squid
          receptors.

Source


I found a full movie of this on YouTube, with some white steak overlay, and found the arcade scene.  It seems like it's the right movie, but I'm not 100% sure.  I'll wait to see if someone else has another idea on what it could be before I mark this as the correct answer.
